# Why is the executable not loading my cli file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am following the gem guide in the [bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.13/guides/creating_gem.html).

when i reached the command line part where i have to require 'foodie/cli' on the executable, i keep getting error.

```
/Users/suyesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- foodie/cli (LoadError)
    from /Users/suyesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from exe/foodie:2:in `<main>'
```

here is my code in the executable

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'foodie/cli'

Foodie::CLI.start
```

here is my cli which is in lib/foodie/cli.rb

```
require 'thor'
require 'foodie'


module Foodie
  class CLI < Thor
    desc "portray ITEM", "Determines if a piece of food is gross or sdeliciour."
    def portray(name)
      puts Foodie::Food.portray(name)
    end
  end
end
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where is you executable placed?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you call your executable and how your paths are set up it should work (tm).

Use `bundle exec path/to/my/executable` in your development environment (assuming you are writing a gem - which is nearly always a good idea). If you followed the other steps in the Bundler tutorial I believe you should have a gemspec file which tells bundler where to look for ([lib/]foodie/cli.rb).

Use `ruby -Iinc/lude/dir/for/example/lib path/to/my/executable` to tell your ruby to (temporarily) also look in the directory `inc/lude/dir/for/example/lib` for source files (in your case foodie/cli.rb). Since you are learning bundler, dont use this approach, but it might be interesting to others, and to cast some light in the area where lib-, load- and include-paths live.